# Apache Nutch Command Unable to Execute

Tags: apache, nutch

I followed each and every step in the [Apache Nutch Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). I am using MacOSX 10.8.3, my `JAVA_HOME` is perfectly set and can even see various command options when `bin/nutch` is executed (according to the wiki).

But when I use `bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5`, I get the following error:

```
bin/nutch: line 104: [: too many arguments
Error: Could not find or load main class Engines
```

FYI: I have already created a `urls` directory in `apache-nutch-1.6/urls`

Can any one tell what might be the problem?

Comment: Can you say your command is running  on which file path (response of `pwd` command)?

Answer (score 0):

you can try as follow:

First of all, build nutch via ant.

`cd nutch-1.x.x/runtime/local/`

`mkdir urls` (for seed list directory)

`mkdir crawl` (for `-dir` option)

`vim urls/seed` , then you add one or more than one url (ex:http://www.examplesite.com)

`bin/nutch crawl urls` --or-- `bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5`

Answer (score 0):

After some research I figured out that I forgot to set the NUTCH_JAVA_HOME.
Here is the step:

```
set NUTCH_JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
export NUTCH_JAVA_HOME
```

And yes I reset the JAVA_HOME as well:

```
set JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home
export JAVA_HOME
```