# Getting error while running Nutch on OSX mavrics

Tags: osx-mavericks, nutch

I run the following command and I get an error of class not found. I tried run the following

$ bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
bin/nutch: line 106: [: too many arguments
Error: Could not find or load main class Course.Web

[Apache Nutch Command Unable to Execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521582/apache-nutch-command-unable-to-execute)
I tried both the approaches from the above link but none of them worked.

I am using Nutch 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem...

Folder name had a ' ' in it. that caused nutch crawl to not work.

After removing the space character from the folder name, it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nutch 2.x .Command /bin/nutch crawl is deprecated. You should use /bin/crawl instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am using Nutch 1.7 sorry forgot to mention initially